# React TextInput reference in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In typescript, I have `const searchField = React.useRef<TextInput>(null)`;

`searchField.current.focus();` rightfully complains that `Object is possibly 'null'` - fine! So I write `searchField.current?.focus();` where the `?` is supposed to act as a if operator of sort, right?

So if I get it correctly, it's basically saying "if I have a `searchField.current` then do something, otherwise not", in which case it still complains with `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`.

If I write the if statement below, it stops complaining:

```
if (searchField.current) {
  searchField.current.focus();
}
```

But isn't it the same as `searchField.current?.focus();`? What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1241#issuecomment-556027910 Does this help?

Comment: Patrick! Thank you! Going to answer this questions for others thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick pointed out, and [as explained her](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions.md)e, to support for optional call expressions x?.(), and directive in module declarations, you need to add the following rules to your eslint json file:

```
"no-unused-expressions": "off",
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": ["error"]
```